# It there still any threashold limitation on modern UI list views

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-view-threshold, modern, threshold

Previously inside sharepoint 2010 & 2013 on-premises we were not able to show more than 5,000 items inside list views. for example if we filter the items based on their status (for example status = Open), and there are more than 5,000 items with Open status we will get an error.. but in sharepoint online using the modern UI, i can see that there is no more any restrictions, and inside modern UI we are able to search/filter lists view even if the result contain more than 5,000 items .. so is my assumption that modern UI no more have the 5,000 threshold issue? if the answer is yes, then is still any type of thresholds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Still the same list view threshold in SharePoint online:

> You can store up to 30 million items or files in a list or library.
> Filtered views of large lists have a similar experience to other
> lists. However, when a list view shows more than 5000 items, you may
> run into a list view threshold error.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/items-exceeds-list-view-threshold

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#ID0EABAAA=Modern

Comment: but based on my test i am ale to filter/search the list view even if they have more than 5000 items

Comment: Even if the issue doesn't happen now, it's recommended to keep list view items within the limit.